# svm accuracy code in matlab

Tags: matlab, svm

I'm working on a data set for user authentication, and I want to divide my train data as impostor and valid user. It has 31 features and 51 users.

I have 200 samples for train and 200 samples for test. This is my code:

```
ttrain=[train;train2]    
group=[repmat(1,100,1);repmat(2,100,1)]     
model=svmtrain(ttrain,group,'kernel_function','rbf')     
testoutput=svmclassify(model,test,'Showplot','false')
```

but when I want to calculate accuracy with code below, it shows error:
`"Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'struct'."`

```
acc = sum(model == testoutput) ./ numel(testoutput)
```

What should I do?

Comment: could you clarify a little bit? Above you say that your train data has 31 features and 51 users. To me that sounds like that there are 51 examples in your training set. Below, you state your training data consisted of 200 examples. What do the "51 users" mean?

Answer (score 0):

model is SVMStruct and therefore cannot be compared by using "==". What you want to do, is to count how many examples your SVM predicted correctly and divide that number by the total number of examples tested.

I would assume you have to do something like this with the following precondition:

- correctLabels are the labels that are correct for the examples you
  test the svm for:

  acc = sum(correctLabels == testoutput) / numel(correctLabels)